# "Forbidden", cannot authenticate using JAAS (WildFly)

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jaas

I've done it as it is described in all the tutorials.

1. Add MySql connetion jar as a module to WildFly (mySql-conn-driver.jar)

`module add --name=com.mysql --resources=/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api`

`/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql,driver-module-name=com.mysql,driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)`

2. Added DataSource

`[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=niwads:add(
    driver-name=mysql,
    user-name=db_user,
    password=secret,
    connection-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdb,
    min-pool-size=5,
    max-pool-size=15,
    jndi-name=java:/jdbc/niwads,
    enabled=true,
    validate-on-match=true,
    valid-connection-checker-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker,
    exception-sorter-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter
)`

3. Created Security Domain with GUI in Browser, not CLI. With final result was like this:

   ```
   <security-domain name="niwasdnew" cache-type="default">
   <authentication>
       <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
           <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jbdc/niwads" /> 
           <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password as 'Password' from user_account where nickname=?" />
           <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select r.rolname as 'Role', r.rolname as 'RoleGroup' from user_account u, role r where r.id=u.role_key and u.nickname=?" />
       </login-module>
   </authentication>
   ```
4. Created and added *jboss-web.xml* to WEB-INF:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-web>
           <security-domain>niwasdnew</security-domain>
   </jboss-web>
   ```
5. My *web.xml* with *FORM* authentication roles and so so:

   ```
   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>pages for masters</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/sections/master/*</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
           <role-name>admin</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>pages for gardeners</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/sections/gardener/*</url-pattern>
           <http-method>GET</http-method>
           <http-method>POST</http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
           <role-name>gardener</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <login-config>
       <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
       <form-login-config>
           <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
           <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
       </form-login-config>
   </login-config>

   <security-role>
       <role-name>admin</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-role>
       <role-name>gardener</role-name>
   </security-role>
   ```

After all this, I start my project on WildFly, I see my welcome page, go to login page, fill needed fields press Login Button **and it redirects me to appropriate place depend on user's role**

BUT I see only the "Forbidden" error page!

What I'm doing wrong? What I've missed?

Comment: A way of testing would be adding a servlet in an unprotected URL and print/log the info from the request (remoteUser, userInRole, etc.)

Comment: @SJuan76 all project uses jsf template, so I show in top of the page user info, and when i go back to welcome page it shows me user info, like user passed authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found the answer to my question. On this [recourse](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DatabaseServerLoginModule)
It shows me that I make a mistake at **step 3** where I write `module-option name="rolesQuery"` in SQL sentense: *select r.rolname as 'Role', **r.rolname as 'RoleGroup'** from user_account u, role r where r.id=u.role_key and u.nickname=?*

From resource

> Note: Value of RoleGroup column always has to be Roles (with capital 'R'). This is specific to JBoss.

So propper SQL sentence do work, in my case — *select r.rolname as 'Role', **'Roles' as 'RoleGroup'** from user_account u, role r where r.id=u.role_key and u.nickname=?* — the right answer